# three.js: PerspectiveCamera: disable zoom

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to disable zooming with the mousewheel.

The api of the camera:
http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera

I can't see any way to do that unless read the source code :S
I have done many google searches but I did not find a solution.

Any idea?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using OrbitControls or TrackballControls in your code? Because these controls will enable your mouse interaction in three.js. If yes, then you need to set "true" of the "noRotate" attribute of those contols. Please check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`PerspectiveCamera` will not zoom automatically when using the mouse wheel. I believe you are using some demo code that implements this behaviour.